# Ehrenfest Paradox

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

If an observer is inside a carousel in circular motion and turns on a light after the light rays complete one full rotation around the carousel, will the light rays reach the observer simultaneously or at different times?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: They return at a different times.**

This is the basis of Sagnac gyroscopes that use the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagnac_effect.

I am assuming you use a series of mirrors or a fibre optic cable to guide the light around the circumference with no short cutting across the interior. The delay is proportional to the enclosed area of the light paths and the angular velocity of the rotating object.

The reason the light rays arrive at different times is because one ray is chasing the finish point and trying to catch up with it, while for the other ray, the inish point is coming towards the ray and the travel time is shorter.

It is also an indication of why it is difficult to arrange a global coordinate system around the perimeter of an object in the Ehrenfest paradox, because in the rotating reference frame of the carousel, the apparent speed of light is different in different direction and it is impossible to synchronise natural clocks all the way around the perimeter.

You can however synchronise clocks in a local portion of the perimeter of the carousel and also calibrate by using radar measurements that use the average of the two way speed of light, which is equal to the normal speed of light. Note that it is well known, that when determining the speed of light in the normal linear case, we are unable to determine the one way speed of light.